# JTable setvalueat stackoverflow

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am getting stackoverflow error when I try to change one of columns data when 2 columns of the columns has been edited.

I have 3 columns which are `items, quantity, price`.

I want to calculate the price when items and quantity has an input. Below is my code:-

```
itemsTable.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < itemsTable.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    if (itemsTable.getValueAt(i, 0) != null) {
                        String item = itemsTable.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
                        double price = Double.parseDouble(selectedItem.substring(item.indexOf("RM") + 2, item.length())); //get price from the cell
                        double qty = Double.parseDouble(itemsTable.getValueAt(i, 1).toString()); //get quantity from cell
                        itemsTable.setValueAt(price * qty, i, 2); //calculate price * qty and set price
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

I set a combobox that loaded with database data to `items` column and a JSpinner for `quantity`

What am I doing wrong? I am new to JTable.

**EDIT**
[image]

**Answer:(credits to Titus)**

```
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE && e.getColumn() != 2) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < itemsTable.getRowCount(); i++) {
                        if (itemsTable.getValueAt(i, 0) != null) {
                            ...
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: 1) Your method is called whenever table data changes. 2) Then, inside your method, you change table data. This leads to 1). Your method is called recursively until there is no more space on the call stack.

Comment: So, How do I achieve my desire result? What and how is the appropriate way to do it?

Comment: You can add a check like `if(e.getColumn() != 2){...}` to ignore change events triggered by setting the "Price" value. You can also check if the value for the "Price" column was set: `if(itemsTable.getValueAt(i, 0) == null)`.

Answer (score -1):

Also wouldn't hurt to limit the loop to going from row e.getFirstRow() thru e.getLastRow(), and maybe updating price in an invokeLater process as well.  But titus hit it head on: gotta stop the infinite cascade of change invokes handler which makes change that invokes handler which makes change...